# Error 26 on SQL with C#, error locating server / instance specified

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlconnection

I am a little new to C# and SQL Server, and I am trying to connect to a SQL Server database with the following function:

```
private SqlConnection openDatabase() 
{
    String connStr = "Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\usuariosDB.sdf;Password=senh@1;Persist Security Info=True";
    SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(connStr);
    sqlcon.Open();

    return sqlcon;
}
```

However, when this function is called the Visual Studio debug throws the error 26, that is error locating server / instance specified. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you appear to have a formatting issue with the ConnectionString.. as stated in one of the answers you should look at [C# Connection Strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-compact/) for some help on the syntax here.  I suspect you need to provide an actual directory path, instead of `|DataDirectory|`, inside your connection string.

The error you are getting indicates SqlConnection object cannot connect to that server, because it does not exist, which most likely means there is a problem with the path you provided.

Comment: connectionstrings.com has helped me numerous times. +1

Comment: Thank you for your answer Slider. But I still get the error. I have built a new database on the same directory as the program. The connection string I am using is: "Data Source=usuariosDB.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;" . And I still get the error...

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer here:

[SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0: Error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16874746/sql-server-compact-edition-4-0-error-26-error-locating-server-instance-speci?rq=1)

SQL Compact needs SqlCeConnection objects, not SqlConnection !!!

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example of a connection string I'm using:

```
public const string ConStr = "Data Source=SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True";
```

Hope it helps ;)